# Not able to add a value dynamically in select tag using Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, jsp-tags

Its a very simple question, but yet not able to find the solution. I'm able to print a value without 0's in the page, but not able to bind the values to a `<select>` tag in options.

**My code is:**

```
${sa.replace("0", "")} displays numbers without 0's
```

But, the options with the values doesn't display in the UI

```
<option value="<s:property value="%{#sa}"/>" <s:if test="%{#sa == #sumAssured.toString()}"> selected="" </s:if> >
                                    <span class="eurosymbol formatAmount"><span>                 <s:property value="%{#sa.replace('0','')}"/></span></span>
                                </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use objects in OGNL, the object should be in the value stack. You can use `attr` object to search in other scopes.

```jsp
<option value="<s:property value='%{#attr.sa}'/>" 
  <s:if test="%{#attr.sa == #attr.sumAssured.toString()}"> selected="selected"</s:if>>
  <span class="eurosymbol formatAmount"><span><s:property value="%{#attr.sa.replace('0','')}"/></span></span>
</option>
```